# VBA Run-Time error '424': Object required

Tags: excel, vba, object

I am trying to create a print function that selects from a range at the bottom of a long list. The Macro works but it gives me an error every time of 'Object Required' after the macro completes. I cannot figure out how to clean this up and prevent the error from occurring.

```
Option Explicit
Sub SchedulePrint()

    Dim lRow As Range
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Sheets("Line 3")

        Set lRow = Range("G1024").End(xlUp).Offset(-3, -6).Resize(20, 14).PrintOut
'The above is the line where I get the debug error message
    
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: adding a period before the `range` will tell VBA what it wants.

Comment: The With structure implies a "." before the range statement.

Comment: ... also remove `Set lRow = ` i.e. when you added `.PrintOut`, the right side was no longer a range object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Object Required

This line is blowing up:

```
Set lRow = Range("G1024").End(xlUp).Offset(-3, -6).Resize(20, 14).PrintOut
```

Because the `Range.PrintOut` method returns nothing (it's a `Sub`, not a `Function`), so what's going on is that the right-hand side of the assignment gets evaluated. Since it's a side-effecting statement on the right-hand side, the side-effects happen as the expression is evaluated (i.e. you *do* get a printout). This should really be a compile-time error, but the VBA compiler is known to defer many checks to run-time, so...

VBA then takes the result of the RHS expression and attempts to honor the `Set lrow` instruction... but the RHS didn't yield any object reference, so you get an *object required* error, because when you have `Set xyz` on the LHS of an assignment, the RHS *must* evaluate to an object reference.

The solution is to remove the side-effect from the assignment:

```
Set lRow = Range("G1024").End(xlUp).Offset(-3, -6).Resize(20, 14)
```

Now the RHS evaluates to the result of `Range.Resize`, which is a `Range` object. So `lrow` holds a reference to that `Range` when this instruction completes.

Now another instruction can call the `PrintOut` method of that `Range` object:

```
lRow.PrintOut
```

But there's another problem.

---

#### Implicit ActiveSheet Reference

There's a stated intent here:

```
With Sheets("Line 3")
```

It looks like the intent is to work off a worksheet that's named `Line 3`, however the `Range` function isn't *qualified*, so it will behave differently depending on where in the project the code is written:

- In a worksheet module, `Range` refers to a range of cells *on that worksheet*.
- In any other module type, `Range` refers to *whatever the active sheet is*.

So if the macro is written in the code-behind of the `Line 3` worksheet, then the `With` block is redundant, because the unqualified `Range` call is always going to be referring to the correct worksheet. The implicit containing workhseet reference can be made more explicit by qualifying with `Me`, i.e. use `Me.Range(...)` instead of just `Range`. If it's written in the code-behind of another worksheet, then the code is misleading because it is *not* working off the `Line 3` worksheet (rather, it refers to whatever worksheet module the macro is written in).

If the macro is written in any other module, then there's an implicit requirement that `Line 3` is also the `ActiveSheet` when the macro runs, otherwise it won't produce the expected result.

The wrong way to fix it is to activate that particular worksheet before you access a `Range`:

```
With Sheets("Line 3")
    .Activate
    Set lRow = Range(...)
```

That's wrong, because the `With` block is still useless. The *correct* way to fix it is to use the `With` block variable as a qualifier - then it doesn't matter which worksheet is active anymore:

```
With Sheets("Line 3")
    Set lRow = .Range(...)
```

Similarly, `Sheets` is implicitly referring to whatever the active *workbook* is, unless the code is written in the `ThisWorkbook` module - in which case `Sheets` is implicitly `Me.Sheets`, and if we know we're after a `Worksheet` type of sheet, we should be using the `Worksheets` collection instead. In any other module, `Sheets` (or `Worksheets`) used without a qualifier, refers to *whatever workbook is currently active* - which may or may not be the containing workbook. Use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("...")` to retrieve a `Worksheet` from the workbook that contains the macro.

See the following [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com)<sup>*</sup> inspections for more details:

- [Implicit ActiveWorkbook reference](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveWorkbookReference)
- [Implicit ActiveSheet reference](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference)
- [Implicit Containing Workbook reference](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitContainingWorkbookReference)
- [Implicit Containing Worksheet reference](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitContainingWorksheetReference)
- [Set assignment with incompatible object type](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/SetAssignmentWithIncompatibleObjectType)

---

<sub><sup>*</sup>Rubberduck is a free and open-source VBIDE add-in project I maintain.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I only submitted a section for one of the sheets of this workbook but your suggestions for making the Range refer back to the sheet that calls for it as well as moving the .PrintOut to a new line and having it call directly to the lRow resolved the code. I have now updated this to affect all of the remaining lines/ sheets, they all needed their own unique offsets values but it works like a charm now.

Answer (score 1):

What @freeflow and @vbasic2008 both said is correct. Since you selected the "Line 3" worksheet first using the "With" statement the following Range needs to be proceeded with a period so that It's associated with the selected sheet.

It looks as if you then tried to set the range "LROW" at the same time as you were running the PrintOut function. Since the PrintOut method returns a variant and not a range Excel throws and error.

If you need to set lRow as a range it's best to set lRow first. Then use it after it's been set.

```
Set lRow = .Range("G1024").End(xlUp).Offset(-3, -6).Resize(20, 14)
lRow.PrintOut
```

It's also possible to avoid setting lRow at all and just call the printout function

```
.Range("G1024").End(xlUp).Offset(-3, -6).Resize(20, 14).PrintOut
```

Comment: Ha, I hadn't checked and just assumed `Range.PrintOut` was a `void|/`Sub`, kudos for a good answer, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Mathiedu_Guindon great answer I could suggest reducing the code as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub SchedulePrint()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Sheets("Line 3").Range("G1024").End(xlUp).Offset(-3, -6).Resize(20, 14).PrintOut
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```